# Is there a safe way to assert if a string view is null terminated?

Tags: c++, string, assert, c-strings, string-view

I have some part in my code that uses string view extensively. It would be inconceivable to use `std::string` everywhere, and `char const*` won't work since there is associative containers, many comparisons and such operations that are hard to do with plain raw strings.

However, there is a place that will eventually deal with a C API, and it needs null terminated strings:

```
auto sv = std::string_view{/* ... */};
c_api(sv.data());
```

Although this works fine in my case, I'd like to be sure everything is okay and assert that the strings are null terminated, as my system constructing the string views and send it there will not use substring views, and will either make them from string literals or `std::string`. I know I will be okay.

The thing however is that another programmer may not know all of this and try to use `substr` on a string view, or send a non null terminated string. A non null terminated string is bad since it will lead to undefined behaviour, but a substring in the string view is even worse, since the upper limit will not be applied when sent to the C API and no undefined behavior will be invoked, but will instead introduce a really hard to find bug with unintended behavior.

So I wanted to communicate that using an assert:

```
auto sv = std::string_view{/* ... */};
assert(*(sv.data() + sv.length()) == '\0'); // Yay?
c_api(sv.data());
```

But I find it incomplete and error prone, since it may read out of bound of a null terminated string.

Is there a way to safely assert that a string view is indeed null terminated?

Comment: maybe not relevant, but `std::string` can have `\0` in the middle, which can also cause trouble when a null-terminated string is expected

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that's true. This is where contract could be handy and simply specify that a expect a "c compatible" string.

Comment: It might be a pain, but I would write my own `string_view` that is guaranteed to be null terminated. I don't think there is a portable way to tell since `*(sv.data() + sv.length())` will be UB if the `string_view` points to a non null terminated buffer that is `length()` wide.

Comment: Also, `sv.data()` may return a `nullptr`.

Comment: I would probably just pass `const std::string&` instead of `std::string_view`. Use `std::string_view` for new APIs that you are creating that do not rely on other libraries.

Comment: No problem.  Want that written up as an answer?

Comment: @Galik I have measured and using `std::string` there cannot be done without a noticeable performance hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a pain, but I would write my own `string_view` that is guaranteed to be null terminated.

Since a `string_view` can be constructed like

```
char array[3] = {'B', 'a', 'r'};
std::string_view array_v(array, sizeof array);
```

testing

```
*(sv.data() + sv.length()) == '\0'
```

is undefined behavior in that case since the last valid index is `2` but you access `3`.  `std::string_view` would need to exposes information it can't know in order for you to do this and since it can't, you can't reliably know.